# complexity of recersive function nestedin a loop

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Im trying to calculate the complexity of a recursive call inside a loop:

```
Calculate(n,m){
for(i=1; i<n; i++){
    if(n==1) return 1;
    Calculate(n-1,m);
 }
for(j=1; i<m; i++){
    Calculate(n,m-1);
    if(m==1) return 1;
} 
}
```

here is what i did to calculate it :

```
C(m,n) = 1 + C(m-1,n) + C(m-2,n) + .... + C(1,n) 
           + C(m,n-1) + C(m,n-2) + .... + C(m,1)
```

is the complexity = 2^(m+n) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: to reduce either `m` or `n` by 1, you need to make 2 calls; since you need to reduce both of them to zero, you need to go through `O(m+n)` 'levels'.

Thus the number of calls is `O(2^(m+n))`.

Comment: i'm not sure but to reduce m or n by 1 we need to make m-1 + n-1 call .aren't we ??

Comment: Yes, but when we talk about complexity, we are only concerned about the highest-order terms. `O(m+n-2)` is the same as `O(m+n)`.

Comment: Ok thanks but i still didn't really understand why it's 2^??

Comment: Because every recursion makes 2 calls, so you're going to have `1+2+4+8+...+2^(m+n-2)` calls, which is equal to `2^(m+n-1)`.

Comment: There is two calls each one in loop then it will not be  only two calls

Comment: Start with `f(n,m)`. This calls `f(n-1,m)` and `f(n,m-1)`. That's 1+2 so far. Then `f(n-1,m)` calls `f(n-2,m)` and `f(n-1,m-1)`, while `f(n,m-1)` calls `f(n-1,m-1)` and `f(n,m-2)`. That's 1+2+4. And so on. This goes on n+m-2 times; try this with m = 3 and n = 3 if it's not clear.

Comment: Yes i undersanted this, but i see that there is one missing thing, which is that f(n,m) does not only call f(n-1,m) and f(n,m-1), it n calls in the first loop, and it makes m calls in the second loop.
So every recursion does not make only 2 calls, it makes n + m calls ...

Comment: Every recursion makes 2 function calls. This is what it means to be a recursion: Each call spawns more calls, but those calls are part of a recursion, which is when we add the next level. Have you actually tried this for n = m = 3 like I suggested?

Comment: f(3,3)= f(3,2) + f(3,1) + f(2,3) + f(1,3)?? this is what i had when i used the aglo

Comment: f(3,3) calls f(3,2) and f(2,3), then f(3,2) calls f(3,1), and f(2,2). You're missing f(2,2) among other things, and this is literally copy-pasting what I commented earlier with values substituted in for n and m.